# Binary print with printf() possible this way?

Tags: c, binary, printf, stm32, usart

During programming on STM32 MCU, found difficulties to use `printf()` function for sending data over USART for binary codes. Found solution that may be wrong, but works for me:

```
uint8_t bin = 0xAA;
printf("Converting number to binary 0b%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d\n",bin>>7&1,bin>>6&1,bin>>5&1,bin>>4&1,bin>>3&1,bin>>2&1,bin>>1&1,bin&1);
```

This is my first post, so bear with me, please.

Comment: What is your question ? Please see: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the code fragment posted does produce the binary representation of the byte `bin`.

Note however that you should change the presentation to improve readability: the counter intuitive precedence order between `>>` and `&` deserves some redundant parentheses to avoid ambiguity.

```
uint8_t bin = 0xAA;
printf("Converting number to binary 0b%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d\n",
       (bin >> 7) & 1, (bin >> 6) & 1, (bin >> 5) & 1, (bin >> 4) & 1,
       (bin >> 3) & 1, (bin >> 2) & 1, (bin >> 1) & 1, (bin >> 0) & 1);
```